# Fraction walk through

Tags: fractions

> $$0.824 = \frac{n/20\cdot 1}{n/20\cdot 1+(1-n/20)\cdot 0.5}$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro1uS.png)

Please answer this question with step by step. Thank you so much

Comment: This site is a place to get help. Not a service for doing math problems (while showing steps!) for free. What have you done yourself to try to solve for $n$? What specifically is your difficulty with this problem?

Comment: Be a math smarty and show your progress; it's the best way to learn! :) Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

...........................................

[image]